# How to make Proxy Checker faster

Tags: c#, multithreading, proxy

I made a simple proxy checker but the problem is it is very slow. It takes much time because it checks one after one. I want to make it check +10 proxies in the same time. The question is: How can I make it fast using threads.

This is the simplified code :

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
 {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

  }
    public void addgood() {
        int co = int.Parse(bunifuCustomLabel1.Text);
        co++;
        bunifuCustomLabel1.Text = co.ToString();
    }
    public void testProxy(string ip, int port)
    {
        bool OK = false;
        try
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Proxy = new WebProxy(ip, port);
            wc.DownloadString("http://google.com/ncr");
            OK = true;
            addgood();
            richTextBox2.Text +=ip+":"+port+"\n";
        }
        catch { }
    }

    private void bunifuFlatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "TXT Files | *.txt";
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            proxy_list.Text = File.ReadAllText(@fileName);
            proxy_list.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private void bunifuFlatButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String ip;
        int port;
        if (proxy_list.Lines.Length < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Proxy list is Vide");
        }
        else { 
            foreach(String i in proxy_list.Lines){
                String[] tab = i.Split(':');
                port = int.Parse(tab[1]);
                ip = tab[0];
                testProxy(ip , port);
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at `Tasks` or `Parallel.ForEach`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an async implementation to your testProxy:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void addgood()
        {
            int co = int.Parse(bunifuCustomLabel1.Text);
            co++;
            bunifuCustomLabel1.Text = co.ToString();
        }
        public async Task testProxy(string ip, int port)
        {
            bool OK = false;
            try
            {
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                wc.Proxy = new WebProxy(ip, port);
                await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri("http://google.com/ncr"));
                OK = true;
                addgood();
                richTextBox2.Text += ip + ":" + port + "\n";
            }
            catch { }
        }

        private void bunifuFlatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "TXT Files | *.txt";
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                proxy_list.Text = File.ReadAllText(@fileName);
                proxy_list.Refresh();
            }
        }

        private void bunifuFlatButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (proxy_list.Lines.Length < 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Proxy list is Vide");
            }
            else
            {
                var asyncTasks = new Task[proxy_list.Lines.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < proxy_list.Lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    var tab = proxy_list.Lines[i].Split(':');
                    asyncTasks[i] = testProxy(tab[0], int.Parse(tab[1]));
                }
                Task.WaitAll(asyncTasks);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And if you want to see just the differences take a look here: https://github.com/heldersepu/csharp-proj/commit/9f9b33eccfc36e21a6f6e1cf3afb861e934e3ab3

Comment: You can improve the code by not waiting for then one by one but concurrent by replacing the `foreach` with the `task.Wait()` with `Task.WaitAll(asyncTasks);`, or better yet, `await Task.WhenAll(asyncTasks);`

Comment: Thank's @PeterBons I will edit my answer with your suggestion

Comment: @HelderSepu I can't using " System.Threading.Tasks; " is give me error in Tasks I'm use visual studio 2012

Comment: @KonesJone Sounds like a good time to upgrade ... Visual Studio 2017 Community edition is free